# How can I paste paragraph not to interrupt numbers in list org mode?

Tags: org-mode, list

In list environment, after I copy several paragraphs, the next  item number will change into number 1, How can I
deal with that?

For example,

```
1. aaa
2. aaa
3. aaa
bbb    <---this is what I copied
ccc
1. aaa <---I want it becomes 4
```

Comment: All you need is to add space before `bbb` and `ccc`. Or are you asking about how to add space automatically upon copying?

Comment: @wvxvw add space automatically might be good

Comment: You would probably need to advise `yank` and pad the strings you insert with as many spaces as the current indentation level... but this seems like a low of work. If you don't encounter this problem very often, you could just insert region (of blanks) before the inserted text: a bit slower, but easier to do.

Comment: you can use `(org-get-indentation)` to find the indentation.  then you could use a temp buffer to add the necessary amount of space for each line, before inserting it into your buffer.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a good idea to adjust the yanked region directly on `yank`. The indent is syntactic relevant for the structure of an org-file. If you copy-paste already structured text the structure would get lost through the adjustments.

I propose that you leave `yank` as it is and use the following command `org-adjust-region` that re-adjusts all the stuff in the current region according to the preceeding stuff.

I have bound this function to <kbd>C-+</kbd>.

You can install the lisp snippet below in your init file.
In your use case you just press <kbd>C-+</kbd> right after pasting and see what happens...

```lisp
(require 'org)
(defun org-adjust-region (b e)
  "Readjust stuff in region according to the preceeding stuff."
  (interactive "r") ;; current region
  (save-excursion
    (let ((e (set-marker (make-marker) e))
      (_indent (lambda ()
             (insert ?\n)
             (backward-char)
             (org-indent-line)
             (delete-char 1)))
      last-item-pos)
      (goto-char b)
      (beginning-of-line)
      (while (< (point) e)
    (indent-line-to 0)
    (cond
     ((looking-at "[[:space:]]*$")) ;; ignore empty lines
     ((org-at-heading-p)
      (error "Headings cannot be balanced (yet)."))
     ((org-at-item-p)
      (funcall _indent)
      (let ((struct (org-list-struct))
        (mark-active nil))
        (ignore-errors (org-list-indent-item-generic -1 t struct)))
      (setq last-item-pos (point)))
     ((org-at-block-p)
      (funcall _indent)
      (goto-char (plist-get (cadr (org-element-special-block-parser e nil)) :contents-end))
      (org-indent-line))
     (t (funcall _indent)))
    (forward-line))
      (when last-item-pos
    (goto-char last-item-pos)
    (org-list-repair)
    ))))


(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-+") 'org-adjust-region)
```

Answer (score 2):

Paragraph `bbb\nccc` is not part of item 3:

```
1. aaa
2. aaa
3. aaa
bbb    <---this is what I copied
ccc
4. [@4] aaa <---I want it becomes 4
```

Paragraph `bbb\nccc` is a separate paragraph within item 3

```
1. aaa
2. aaa
3. aaa

   bbb    <---this is what I copied
   ccc
4. aaa <---I want it becomes 4
```

Comment: Item 4 starts a separate list with the method in the first text snippet. If you insert an additional item below item 2 `org-list-repair` does not work as expected. The first list runs from 1 to 4 and the next one starts at 4?! I do not know how you get from the first text snippet to the second one. Selecting a region and running `org-indent` does work for this small example but not in the general case where there are several items in the pasted text. That is the point where I started to write down my solution.

Comment: Note also that you need to preserve the indentation of code blocks in the inserted text. I do not yet know what to do with headlines. Do we want to demote them? I do also not yet know what to do with drawers.

Comment: tobias: re first message.  yes they are separate lists.  The first element is a `plain-list` of items; the second element is a `paragraph`; the third element is again a `plain-list`.  To verify use `org-element-at-point` at pos `0`, `22`, and `59`.  The second list starts at 4 because of the `@` operator, and it's the point of the exercise.  The second example is independent of the first and it seems we are trying to solve different problems.  I simply show how to make the paragraph either a separate element or part of the `item` starting at pos `15`.