# Indent several lines in org mode

Tags: org-mode

I'm a new user to Emacs and I'm using ORG mode to start with.
When I create a list of items, sometimes I copy and paste data from other locations - forming a list of unstructured items.

1. How to make them with the same indent?
2. How to make them check list items by selecting them all in one go?

I tried all that is available [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Multi_002dline-Indent.html#Multi_002dline-Indent) for indentation in vain. Where should I be looking for this information?

Comment: You can use the code from my answer in http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19252/how-can-i-paste-paragraph-not-to-interrupt-numbers-in-list-org-mode/19278#19278. Note: The answer did not score there but I am using the code quite some time now and it is good. Contact me when you encounter any problems.

Comment: I copy pasted your code in my `.emacs` file and tried to execute `CTRL`-`+`. Emacs buffer tells me that `CTRL`-`+` is undefined. I'm new to editing the emacs file.

Comment: **1st:** Did you restart emacs after editing `.emacs`? **2nd:** `C-+` only works in an `org-mode` buffer. Did you try it with an org-file?

Comment: Bang on! you were right!. I did not restart emacs. Now it works like charm. Thanks a lot. +1 to your answer. Can you come to http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35158/discussion-between-tobais-and-prasanna for a  quick chat