# Indenting lists in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, indentation, list

I copied and paste text in an org file and formatted it as a list:

```
- Funded pensions :: As explained more fully in Chapter 3, funded pensions are paid on behalf of its members.
```

How can I have the list formatted as:

```
- Funded pensions :: As explained more fully in Chapter 3, funded pensions are
      paid on behalf of its members.
```

Another simple example where `fill-region-paragraphs`does not work is:

```
* first header

- The primary objective of pensions is /economic security in old age/, achieved
through consumption smoothing, insurance, poverty relief, and redistribution.
- The primary objective of pension design is to /optimize old-age security/, includ-
ing the cost of providing it.
```

Comment: You can fill one single item with `M-q`. But, I believe that you want to fill a region with items.

Comment: I tried with another example. I can't automatically indent nor using M-q, nor `fill-region-as-paragraph` or `fill-region-paragraphs`. I have to manually delete the first line break.

Comment: You should post such an example.

Comment: Please see my edited post.

Comment: Your "other simple example" is another case. There, you do not want `fill-paragraph` alone. In each item the second line starts at the same column as the bullet of the item. The org-syntax says that this line does not belong to the item. This is exactly the reason why there is the command `org-adjust-region`. So, my recommendation for this case is to try `org-adjust-region` **with prefix arg**.

Comment: `org-adjust-region` works with "the simple example", but it also inserts 2 spaces before the symbol `-`. Maybe I am not doing it right "with prefix arg". Is it `TAB` for cycling?

Comment: Yes `org-adjust-region` inserts as many spaces before the bullet as is necessary to get the right org structure. If the item list is the first thing in the org file and you remove `* first header` then `org-adjust-region` does not insert spaces before the bullets. This behavior is intentional.  `org-adjust-region` transforms the text in the current region such that it respects org-syntax.

Comment: I deleted `* first header` and now the list itens are under level `***`. I run `org-adjust-region` and it does not insert spaces before the bullets. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note, the problem with the original version of `paragraph-fill` is that it calls `fill-region` if the region is active. This merges all items into one filled item instead of several filled items.

There follows a command `fill-region-paragraphs` that fills each paragraph with the non-interactive version of `fill-paragraph` instead.
Thus the items in the region are filled separately.
In the code the command is bound to the key sequence <kbd>C-c f</kbd>. You can change this to your likings.

```el
(defun fill-region-paragraphs (b e &optional justify)
  "Fill region between b and e like `fill-paragraph' for each paragraph in region
instead of `fill-region' which is implied by the original version of `fill-paragraph'.
Justify when called with prefix arg."
  (interactive "r\nP")
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char b)
    (while (< (point) e)
      (fill-paragraph justify)
      (forward-paragraph)
      )))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c f") 'fill-region-paragraphs)
```

Below, there is an extented version of the code from [the answer to another question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19252/how-can-i-paste-paragraph-not-to-interrupt-numbers-in-list-org-mode#19872).
I've added `paragraph-fill` to it.

First select the items you want to be filled. Then press the prefix arg <kbd>C-u</kbd> and <kbd>C-+</kbd> to get the formatting you want.

```el
(defun org-adjust-region (b e)
  "Re-adjust stuff in region according to the preceeding stuff."
  (interactive "r") ;; current region
  (save-excursion
    (let ((e (set-marker (make-marker) e))
      (_indent (lambda ()
             (insert ?\n)
             (backward-char)
             (org-indent-line)
             (delete-char 1)))
      last-item-pos)
      (goto-char b)
      (beginning-of-line)
      (while (< (point) e)
    (indent-line-to 0)
    (cond
     ((looking-at "[[:space:]]*$")) ;; ignore empty lines
     ((org-at-heading-p)) ;; just leave the zero-indent
     ((org-at-item-p)
      (funcall _indent)
      (let ((struct (org-list-struct))
        (mark-active nil))
        (ignore-errors (org-list-indent-item-generic -1 t struct)))
      (setq last-item-pos (point))
      (when current-prefix-arg
        (fill-paragraph)))
     ((org-at-block-p)
      (funcall _indent)
      (goto-char (plist-get (cadr (org-element-special-block-parser e nil)) :contents-end))
      (org-indent-line))
     (t (funcall _indent)))
    (forward-line))
      (when last-item-pos
    (goto-char last-item-pos)
    (org-list-repair)
    ))))

(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-+") 'org-adjust-region)
```

In `emacs -Q` 25.1.50.2 I used the following org file `test.org` for testing:

```
* first header

- Funded pensions :: As explained more fully in Chapter 3, funded pensions are paid on behalf of its members.
- Funded pensions :: As explained more fully in Chapter 3, funded pensions are paid on behalf of its members.
- Funded pensions :: As explained more fully in Chapter 3, funded pensions are paid on behalf of its members.
```

Selecting all items as region and calling `fill-region-as-paragraph` resulted into:

```
* first header

- Funded pensions :: As explained more fully in Chapter 3, funded
pensions are paid on behalf of its members.  - Funded pensions :: As
explained more fully in Chapter 3, funded pensions are paid on behalf
of its members.  - Funded pensions :: As explained more fully in
Chapter 3, funded pensions are paid on behalf of its members.
```

which is clearly not what you want.

Applying `fill-region-paragraphs` results into the following text:

```
* first header

- Funded pensions :: As explained more fully in Chapter 3, funded
     pensions are paid on behalf of its members.
- Funded pensions :: As explained more fully in Chapter 3, funded
     pensions are paid on behalf of its members.
- Funded pensions :: As explained more fully in Chapter 3, funded
     pensions are paid on behalf of its members.
```

This text looks to me like what you want.

Running <kbd>C-u C-+</kbd> even gets the indentation right:

```
* first header

  - Funded pensions :: As explained more fully in Chapter 3, funded
       pensions are paid on behalf of its members.
  - Funded pensions :: As explained more fully in Chapter 3, funded
       pensions are paid on behalf of its members.
  - Funded pensions :: As explained more fully in Chapter 3, funded
       pensions are paid on behalf of its members.
```

Comment: I used instead `fill-region-as-paragraph` with good results with only one exception:  in that paragraph, I had first to delete manually the first line break.

Comment: Please see my edited post.